# Fill page with rectangles based on their number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display some divs in my page based on this behavior :
[image]

Depending on the number of divs, they will take up the size of the page until there are 8 of them, then at 9+ they will keep their size and the page will become scrollable.

I thought about using flexboxes like [this](http://www.alsacreations.com/xmedia/tuto/exemples/flexbox/flextest06b.html) but couldn't achieve exactly the expected behavior.

So I started putting a class with JS called "one" if there is one element, "two" for two elements etc. and then with this css (LESS):

```
.container.one {
    div:nth-child(1) {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
.container.two {
    div:nth-child(1) {
        width: 100%;
        height: 75%;
    }
    div:nth-child(2) {
        width: 100%;
        height: 25%;
    }
}
```

etc. up to 8.

It works OK but any better Idea, more concise, would be welcome

Comment: Can you explain when there is one full width div at bottom and half-width divs in middle? Explain algorithm of div placement.

Comment: there is no specific algorithm, the behavior is detailed by the images for each case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The divs fill from the bottom thanks to:

- `display: table` on `<body>`
- `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: bottom` on `<div class="wrap">`

Test by adding and removing divs.

`div:last-child:nth-child(odd)` is the magic sauce to spread the last odd div 100%.

[Have an example!](http://jsbin.com/diqeru/7/edit)

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div><div> 
    <-- ... -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.wrap {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.wrap div {
    border: solid 1px #CCC;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 25%;
}
.wrap div:last-child:nth-child(odd) {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: awesome. used height 25% instead of 80Px and it works damn well. Not exactly as in the images (with 6 divs, the 100% width should be on the second div and not on the last one) but I think the designer is gonna be OK with that

Comment: I was playing around with that concept, and I'm sure it can be done. [Here is a crude](http://jsbin.com/diqeru/9/edit) attempt :) Also, I found a typo `:` on the height in `.wrap`, so be aware.

Comment: just spoke with the designer he is OK if fig. 7 has the 100%width on the bottom. The only problem I have with your first solution is that the first rectangle isn't a real rectangle, it is the empty part of the wrapper; because I must put background-images on the rectangles, I can't place it on the first because it would take up the whole wrapper